# Winforms Custom Dialog hang parent execution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, dialog

I'm attempting to create a custom dialog (using WinForms) that, much like a `ColorDialog` or `OpenFileDialog`, opens and accepts some input from the user, then returns execution to the parent form once input has been recieved.

I attempted to accomplish this by just creating a custom form that had a `Show()` method, then calling it like this:

```
custom_dialog.Show();
var results = custom_dialog.Property;
```

As you could imagine, this did not work as the second line was executed before any input was selected.

My question is: How can I create a custom dialog that will hang the execution of the parent form, as a `ColorDialog` or `OpenFileDialog` does, so that I can force the user to input something before execution continues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should call `ShowDialog()`, this will open the dialog as modal and you will continue execution in the calling form only after dialog has been closed.

It is a good practice to use the `using` block around the modal form so it gets disposed immediately once running out of such block.

Comment: That was easy enough. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You want a modal dialog.  It will pop up and halt all other execution until it is closed.

Something like

```
if(custom_dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
   do something here
else
   do something different
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

> You can use this method to display a
>   modal dialog box in your application.
>   When this method is called, the code
>   following it is not executed until
>   after the dialog box is closed.
>
> The dialog box can be assigned one of
>   the values of the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx)
>   enumeration by assigning it to the
>   DialogResult property of a Button on
>   the form or by setting the
>   DialogResult property of the form in
>   code. This value is then returned by
>   this method.
>
> You can use this return value to
>   determine how to process the actions
>   that occurred in the dialog box.